# Multiplication and inversion preserve the identity component in a Lie group

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let $G_0$ be the connected component of the identity in a Lie group $G$, and let $\mu$ and $i$ be the multiplication map and the inverse map of $G$. I would like to show that for any $x \in G_0$

1. $\mu(\{x_0\} \times G_0) \subset G_0$
2. $i(G_0) \subset G_0$.

For (1), since multiplication is smooth in a Lie group it is necessarily continuous. Moreover, $\{x_0\} \times G_0$ is connected since it is the product of a singleton set and a connected set. Hence, the image of $\mu$ must be connected. I am stuck on showing that this connected image must be a subset of $G_0$. For the second problem, I assume we can use the same reasoning since $i$ is also assumed to be smooth in a Lie group.

Comment: Use the definition of a connected component.

Comment: @LeeMosher The definition of a connected component is that $x$ and $y$ belong to the same connected component if there exists a connected subset that contains both of them. But how do we know in general that for $x,y \in G_0$, $xy \in G_0$ as well? What I have been struggling with is ruling out the situation where multiplication by $x$ sends $y$ outside of $G_0$.

Comment: You wrote yourself: $\{x_0\} \times G_0$ is connected, and so its image under $\mu$ must be connected. And you know a specific element of $G_0$ to which you can apply this statement.

Comment: @LeeMosher Oh yes I see now, that was extremely careless of me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** You haven't yet used the hypotheses that $1 \in G_0$ and $x \in G_0$. Notice that $$\mu(\{x\} \times G_0) \ni \mu(x, 1) = x .$$

Comment: Thank you for the hint. How does that ensure that for all $y \in G_0$ such that $y \neq 1$, $xy \in G_0$? For example, what if multiplication by $x$ keeps some elements in $G_0$ but not for others?

Comment: Like you say, the map $\mu$ is continuous, so the image of the connected set $\{x\} \times G_0$ under $\mu$ is connected. In particular, that image must be contained in a single connected component of $G$.

Comment: I see now. So because the image is connected and we know its image contains an element in common with $G_0$ (the identity element), it must be a subset. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Glad I could help.